# Return each individual item of array as plain strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I have an array that contains a few strings. I want to loop through it and store the result in a variable that I will access as a prop in another component. I want the output to be in the form of individual strings and not return an array. I can use forEach and it returns me the output in the way I want, but we can't return anything in forEach as it is always undefined.

```js
array = ['this', 'is', 'an', 'example']
array.forEach(elem => console.log(elem)) // prints: this
                                         //is
                                         //an
                                         //example
```

How do I return the individual items of an array like the output shown here and store it in a variable? I tried a traditional for-loop but it returns the first element (I did some digging to find that we can use closures but it didn't solve my issue of storing it in a variable). I feel the solution is simple and I'm needlessly complicating it, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: My expected output is:

```
this
is
an
example
```

I want to receive each item of the array as a separate string and need to store these values in a variable. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Just reference `array` again?

Comment: Is `var output = "this is an example"` what you expected result?

Comment: What is your expected output. Add that. Sounds like you are over complicating this stuff

Comment: @YuTing  added the expected result in the question. I need to retrieve all the elements of the array and store them in a variable. The variable is a string containing each item. It is not in the form of a sentence. Hope this helps, thank you.

Comment: @TusharShahi added the expected output in the question and added more info to the earlier comment. Hope it is clearer thank you.

Comment: If you want to return each value and store it in another variable, basically do you want to send the values from an array to another array? or just send all the values to a single variable as string? I really didn't get it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to `join` the array with line breaks.

This is how it should work:

```js
let array = ['this', 'is', 'an', 'example']
let result = array.join('\n')

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

---

I'm not sure if I got it, but I'll give you some examples and hopefully, you can use one of them.

```js
var array = ['this', 'is', 'an', 'example'];

console.log(array.join(' ')); //this is an example

console.log(array.toString()); //this,is,an,example

console.log(array.join('')); //thisisanexample

console.log(array.join('-')); //this-is-an-example
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about *separate* variables, but how about 1 object with separate keys?

```
let array = ['this', 'is', 'an', 'example'];
const obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    obj[i] = array[i];
};
```

...but is that really necessary? You can already access each string in the array by its index:

```
array[0]; // this
array[1]; // is
```

Comment: thank you. My requirement is to store each of the array elements in a single variable. Say, the variable is x. At any point, x should contain the individual words 'this', 'is', 'an', 'example'.

array[0], array[1] give me the desired results, but I want something like finalWords = array[x] // this will return this, is, an, example as separate/unique strings

Comment: Did you check my answer @Praveen? I think I did what you want.

Comment: I'm curious; why do they need to be separate variables? You can already access/edit them within the array.